# PHPList + Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses, phplist

I'm trying to make this run, but I'm getting really crazy. I want to run PHPList with Amazon SES. I've followed this instructions [LINK](http://creative-web-designer.com/2011/12/configure-phplist-for-amazon-ses-and-fix-issue-with-email-address-is-not-verified/) But I get this error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:     Name or service not known (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I can't understand why I get this SMTP error when if I just use SES integration it just have to use cURL. Is there a bug?! or I have to modify something of the code to don't try to connect server.

Of course I tried to define PHPMAILERHOST as amazon smtp host but it fails because it didn't use TLS.

I tried to use PHPMailer with integration with Amazon SES, but non of them work.

Any ideas?!

Comment: IT WORKS PREFECTLY IN PHPLIST 2.11.6, not in 2.11.7

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround here. The workaround is to use postfix that uses SES as relay to send out emails like described in:
http://www.millcreeksys.com/how-to-configure-your-postfix-server-to-relay-email-through-amazon-simple-email-service-ses/

After you do this you can use the mail() command to send emails using your localhost MTA which will relay them further through SES.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have postfix in this servers, junt Apache. But thanks for all!

Comment: We do the same via an exim server on a virtual machine. In any cases latest (still beta) version of phplist includes direct SES support